# Using two pause() to catch two signals but failed

Tags: c, linux

I'm writing a program that forks two children to do something. These two children send two different signals to its parent when their job is done. In the meanwhile, the parent waits for its children using two `pause()`.

However, the program stopped after the first `pause()` and waits for another signal at the second `pause()`. Using gdb, I find that two signals from children are received, but only one `pause()` is finished.

What is the cause of this problem?

In main:

```
struct sigaction parent_act;
struct sigaction child_act[2];

// set the signal handlers
parent_act.sa_handler = &p0_handler;
child_act[0].sa_handler = &p1_handler;
child_act[1].sa_handler = &p2_handler;

// set the behavior when child get signal SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 
sigaction(SIGUSR1, &child_act[0], NULL);
sigaction(SIGUSR2, &child_act[1], NULL);

// fork two child
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    pid[i] = fork();
    // child process
    else if(pid[i] == 0){
        pause(); // wait for signal
        return 0;
    }
}

// set the behavior when parent get signal SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2
sigaction(SIGUSR1, &parent_act, NULL);
sigaction(SIGUSR2, &parent_act, NULL);

kill(pid[0], SIGUSR1); // signal the child to do its job
kill(pid[1], SIGUSR2); // signal the other child to do its job
pause(); // wait for child
pause(); // wait for child
```

In handlers:

```
void p0_handler(int dummy)
{
    return;
}
void p1_handler(int dummy)
{
    // do something
    kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1); // tell parent it's done
    return;
}
void p2_handler(int dummy)
{
    // do something
    kill(getppid(), SIGUSR2); // tell parent it's done
    return;
}
```

First child sends SIGUSR1 to parent and the second one sends SIGUSR2. It seems the first `pause()` received two signals. Is that possible?

Comment: "*different signals*" different in terms of what? The origin only (child1 vs. child2) or alss the number/type/kind/... differs?

Comment: can you add some code please?

Comment: Have you even set up signal handlers?

Comment: Two signals cannot be handled by the `pause` if they arrive at the same instance. It might be that the two child processes are sending the signals at the same time and process scheduling might be playing some nasty tricks.  Depending on when the handler is called, you may lose information during the handler execution, if several signals are sent at the same time.

Comment: And how are you sending signals? which system call are you using?

Comment: I'm using `kill()` to send signals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely both signals arrive at the same time (or the second one arrives during execution of the signal handler) at which point the second `pause` will wait indefinitely.

The problem is that there is no guarantee that even if you like set a flag "One child finished" the other signal does not arrive before `pause` is called.

The only way to make this waterproof with signals is to use `select` on a timeout.

```
int num_signals_received = 0;

void p0_handler(int dummy)
{
    // signal safe action
    __sync_fetch_and_add(&num_signals_received, 1);
    return;
}
```

instead of `pause`:

```
struct timeval timeout = {1,0}; // 1 second
while (num_signals_received < 2)
    select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
```

If you are not set on signals for synchronisation then I would advise you move to either shared memory (`mmap/MAP_SHARED`) or file descriptor based (`pipe(2)`) synchrosisation.

Comment: What if I use a mask that blocks further SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 for the parent's signal handler?

Comment: @Stanley You still can not guarantee that no signal arrives between your last action and setting the signal mask. Trust me: using signals for synchronisation is a bad idea!